# My page displays if there is an image only

Tags: php

This is the weirdest problem I've never met on PHP (I use it since 10 years) and that's why I'm writing this message. PHP version is 7.2.

I think it's not important but i use CodeIgniter, my problem is before, in the first index.php. All works in local, but when I put my code on a server (which is a shared server unfortunately), the behavior is :

- if, in the beginning of index.php, there is an image using data:image with base64, the page displays
- if not, i have a blank page

I just can't understand. I noticed this when i added a phpinfo at the beginning, suddenly my page displayed because the logo of phpinfo uses this kind of picture.

I made many many many tests, and the only way to make it work is using a data:image base64 before (and by the way, just before I use "" to put it in display none and it still works...). Using a link for the image doesn't work.

I have no error, nowhere.

I just want to know if someone has an idea about what is happening here ?

Thank you so much ! (Sorry I'm not an english native person)

Comment: You'll need to post the code of your index.php. Have you checked the server error logs? I suspect you are getting an error, and php on the server is configured to no display those errors to it is silently failing.

Comment: The index.php is the basic one of CodeIgniter Framework. I checked the server logs, there is nothing. I showed up the PHP error with ini_set, there is nothing. No javascript error also. That's why I posted, I'm not a beginner and I always find answers if I need but this case is just insane. And I just wondered if someone could think about something.

Why putting a base64 picture makes the display work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using windows machine for local development. And your server is Linux based...
Linux server is fully case sensitive. Please check folder,files name is correct or not..

If a folder is ../View/123.jpg
Then.  The src="../VIEW/123.JPG"  will work on windows machime. But error in linux server..

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunately, I use Ubuntu in local.
By the way, I have the problem even if I don't use any image. The page displays ONLY when i put a base64 picture, this is totally insane ^^'